# need a help to find python 3.7 rpm for RHEL 8.4

Tags: python, python3

We need a Python 3.7 rpm for RHEL 8.4, I am not able to find this on the official python website. Please share the link or redirect where I get this rpm for download.

We need this rpm as the CDSW 1.10.2 to come with 3.7 kernels and So to work with the pyspark (Spark 2.4) we need to install python 3.7 on all data nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know cdsw very well, but I very strongly assume it brings its own python. Are you sure you are supposed to install python 3.7 yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7 is not available as an rpm for RHEL 8. There's 3.6 and 3.8/3.9 available. **If you want, you can compile it to have it on your system:**

```
dnf install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel

cd /opt && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz

tar xvzf Python-3.7.9.tgz

cd Python-3.7.9

./configure --enable-optimizations

make altinstall
```

After that, you can refer to the binary as `python3.7`